# How to read key from keyboard in c++?

Tags: c++, keyboard

How to read key from keyboard in c++ ?
i used _getch() but this is not working always.

i heard about win32 keyboard api. i am targeting to windows so window specific technique is fine. can anyone give me simple example how to read key and check for arrow and function key.

i read article
[How to simultaneous read keys on keyboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9864383/how-to-simultaneous-read-keys-on-keyboard)

but this is not working in may case. here is my attempt inspired from above linked reference

```
char temp;
BYTE keys[256];
while(true)
{
    temp = _getch();
    if(GetKeyboardState(keys))
    {
        if(keys[VK_UP]&0xF0)
        {
            // Move Up : Case failing when i pressed up key
        }
        else if(keys[VK_DOWN]&0xF0 || keys[VK_RETURN]&0xF0)
        {
            // Move Down : Case failing when i pressed down or enter

        }
        else if(keys[VK_TAB]&0xF0)
        {
            // Move Next : Case failing when i pressed tab
        }
        else
        {
            // Print charecter which read using _getch()
            cout<<temp;
        }

    }
}
```

i read MSDN article but do not understand what they are doing. i am doing such program first time so please make your example clear and illustrative so i can easly get it.  thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a Windows machine at hand to test this out, but I am thinking that the fact that you are using `temp = _getch();` before `GetKeyboardState(keys)` is eating your characters.

Answer (score 0):

there are many library in C++ which handle this type of problem, if you are the choice, I advise you to use QKeySequence and other classes to let useful keyboard management.

If you want to see example, refer you to chromium project, here is an [example](https://github.com/adobe/chromium/blob/master/content/test/mock_keyboard_driver_win.cc) used to test code of "keyboard driver".

you can either search many example with "filetype" syntax in google search engine (example : filetype:cc GetKeyboardState)...

you need to set correctly the layout before use GetKeyboardState...

Hope this help you.

Regards,
/Mohamed

Comment: i think you talking about Qt Library functions. i am not using qt. so thats my constraint.

Comment: Ok ! so you can refer to example of chromium project coded hadly with win32 API for windows os keyboard driver (and indicated in my answer). thx